# Brightness and volume key bindings not working in dwm

Tags: config, volume, key-bindings, brightness

I'm trying to get my volume and brrightness keys to work using dwm.
I put this into dwm/config.h: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohhkq.png

And also this for the keybinds.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwYWp.png

So far I've tried this in my command line

```
sudo make uninstall
sudo make install
```

Then I tried to do the same in root, but that didn't change anything either
I also killed xsessions and booted everything up again and it still doesn't seem to be changing anything.

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to import `XF86keysym`. You can do that by pasting `#include <X11/XF86keysym.h>` on top of your file. I'm no C pro but I was able enabling my volume and brightness keys using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/palopezv/efd34059af6126ad970940bcc6a90f2e). After that import your keys will probably work.

If you are a laptop user and have no dedicated keys for sound/brightness you have to make sure your **FN + F1-F12** (whatever your brightness/sound controls are) are reported as **XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume, XF86XK_AudioMute, XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume** and their corresponding **brightness XF86 codes.** I did that myself using [this post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1742964#p1742964).

For checking your key clicks and what the codes are you can use utilities like `showkey` (hint: use `showkey -a` or `sudo showkey -k`). Or check [this thread](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49650/how-to-get-keycodes-for-xmodmap).

Answer (score 0):

Add `#include <X11/XF86keysym.h>` to `dwm.c` file.